# Running php file by avoiding extension .php in the url without using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cpanel

In my Localhost:
Without using .htaccess, I created a folder named test and a file test.php.
I can run the file from url http://localhost/test/test

In my amazon server with cpanel:
I put the same folder with that file but displays internal server error  after checking the url http://example.com/test/test

I tried:
Changing the Allowoverride None to All
enabling mod rewrite

This is actually for a large project. But using a test in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to rewrite URLs without an htaccess file. That's because you can also use rewrite rules in the Apache configuration files. In a VirtualHost block for example. I guess your localhost is set up that way, so take a look in those server config files.

For your amazon server to work, you either can work with an htaccess file (easiest way) or you can put those rules in the server config files.